# How to create an alias with drag and drop?

Tags: macos, mac, alias, ui

In MacOSX, when dragging a file or folder one can force a copy instead of a move by pressing <kbd>option</kbd>. I think that there used to be a way to alternatively create an alias but can't find which key to press. 
Which key to press when dragging in order to create an alias ?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You must press <kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>option</kbd> while dragging.

Comment: if don't work in Finder window, try to drag first then hold the two buttons. At least in my case it don't work if I hold the two buttons in first hand inside a Finder window.

Answer (score 13):

Hold down  <kbd>cmd</kbd>  and  <kbd>option</kbd>  when dragging.